# How to exit for loop when entire column is empty?

Tags: excel, vba

My code loops through rows and columns and performs an action. I want to loop to the first empty column, however, 
my code keeps looping past this column. My sheet currently looks something like this:

A----------1----------blank---------A---------1

B----------2----------blank---------C---------4

C----------3----------blank---------W---------2

In the above example, I want to loop from k = 1 to the first empty column, which is k = 3 (i.e. only extract data from the first 2 columns then stop the loop).

This is my current code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub exitemptycolumn()

    Dim lastcolumn As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set sh = Sheets("sheetname")
    lastcolumn = sh.Cells(1, Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastrow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For k = 7 to lastcolumn
        for j = 1 TO lastrow
            set rng = sh.Range(columns(1), Columns(k))
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Cells(1, k).EntireColumn) = 0 then Exit For
            'rest of code
        Next j
    Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: Should the loop exit when the *first* cell of that column is blank, or when the *entire* column is blank?

Comment: Use `COUNTA` on the column. With result of zero, `Exit For`

Comment: @BigBen when the entire column is blank as I have some cells in the first 2 columns that are blank and I don't want my loop to exit.

Comment: @JvdV If WorksheetFunction.CountA(columns(k)) = 0 Then Exit For....?

Comment: More like `If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Cells(1, k).EntireColumn) = 0 then Exit For`

Comment: Qualify the worksheet: `sh.Columns(k)`, or `sh.Cells(1, k)`.

Comment: @JvdV please see edit. Is it possible I have a line in the wrong place? The loop still extends past the empty column with the above.

Comment: That's cause you have two loops going. No need to go through rows I think. Since you do nothing with `j`

Comment: It's exiting the wrong for loop. Move it outside the inner for loop.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, it works as intended after switching the loops. Thank you both so much. What do I do to show that my question is answered?

Comment: I wrote it down in an answer, you can close the question. :) Glad it helped you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question, you want to end your loop through columns as soon as the column is completely empty.

We can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA` to do the check like so:

```
For k = 7 to lastcolumn
    set rng = sh.Range(columns(1), Columns(k))
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Cells(1, k).EntireColumn) = 0 then Exit For
Next k
```